# How to fix "net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED 200"

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I realize a ReactJS application with TMDB API, I also use Webpack version 2.2.1, and I randomly get the following error => net :: ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED 200 (OK).

It is possible that I send too much data, gzip compression is necessary but I'm not sure.

As I said it's an error that does not happen all the time, but it's often the same axios query that's about =>

```
async fetchMovies () {
    this.setState({ isLoading:true})

    const promises = genres.map(async genre => {

      const response = await getMoviesWithGenresFromApi(genre.id).then(data 
      => {
        return data.results.slice(0,14)
      })

        return {
            movies:response,
            genretitle:genre.name,
            id:genre.id
        }
     });

    const result = await Promise.all(promises).then((result) => {
        this.setState({
            movieListWithGenre:result,
            hasMore: (this.state.movieListWithGenre.length < 19),
            isLoading:false 
        })
    });
  }
```

AXIOS request:

```
export function getMoviesWithGenresFromApi(id_genre){
  return axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key={api_key}&sort_by=popularity.desc&language=fr&include_adult=false&include_video=false&with_genres=${id_genre}`)
    .then((response) => response.data)
    .catch((error) => console.error(error))
}
```

I would like to determine where this error comes from and what solutions to take to correct this error.

Comment: FoxaLiveJS, did you ever figure this out? I'm getting a similar error client side that seems to only happen for one particular API call. I've seen all sorts of stuff for enabling gzip compression server-side, but nothing was changed server-side in my situation. Is it something with webpack?

Comment: I'm not sure about your case, but I figured out that if I downgrade webpack-dev-server from 3.1.14 to 3.1.10, the ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED error stopped happening. Perhaps it's an issue with your version? Here's where I found my answer: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/1574#issuecomment-453656338

Answer (score 1):

I had encountered a similar issue. I was using JDK 1.8.0_144 which had issues with compression. This bug was fixed in later versions. JDK 1.8.0_202 fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with JDK 1.8.0_192 - for me the problem was that I had added the same header set more then once (Content-Encoding = gzip)

> response.addHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just reuploaded the js file and problem was solved!